# Images not load in view pager using picasso when getting it from local server, but image url shows in logcat

Tags: android

This my Activity code and images not loaded but image url is correctly shown in logcat

```
public class AndroidAppDetailActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
   ProgressBar progressbar;
    public  ArrayList<AndroidApp> appdetails;
    public AndroidAppDetailAdapter appdetailadapter;
    ViewPager viewpager;
    TabLayout tablayout;
    String s;
    TextView txtappdata;
    ImageView playlink;
    String[] strArrayOne;
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_android_app_detail);
        SharedPreference.initialize(getApplicationContext());
        viewpager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewbanners);
        tablayout = (TabLayout)findViewById(R.id.tab_Layout);
        txtappdata=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.txtappdata);
        playlink=(ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imgplay);



        Intent intent=getIntent();
        progressbar= (ProgressBar) findViewById(R.id.progresbar);
        s=intent.getStringExtra(Keys.KeyValue.KEYAPP_ID);
        SharedPreference.save(Keys.SharedPref.SHR_APPID,s);

        Log.i("APPID",s);
        appdetails=new ArrayList<AndroidApp>();
        loadbanner();
    }

    private void loadbanner() {

        progressbar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        StringRequest request = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,Keys.URL.ANDROID_APPDETAILS, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                Log.i("bannerimgees", response);
                progressbar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                try {
                    JSONObject jsonObject;
                    JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                    // JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("");
                    Log.i("length", jsonArray.length() + "");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {

                        JSONObject json = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        //productcategory.add(new Catergoryofproduct(json.getInt("c_id"), json.getString("name"), json.getString("image")));
                        appdetails.add(new AndroidApp("","","",json.getString(Keys.APPDATA.APP_BANNERIMG),json.getString(Keys.APPDATA.APP_DATA),json.getString(Keys.APPDATA.APP_PLAYLINK)));
                        txtappdata.setText(json.getString(Keys.APPDATA.APP_DATA));
                        final String path=json.getString(Keys.APPDATA.APP_PLAYLINK);
                        final String data=json.getString(Keys.APPDATA.APP_BANNERIMG);
                        //string strOne = "One,Two,Three,Four";
                        strArrayOne = new String[] {""};
//somewhere in your code
                        strArrayOne = data.split(",");
                        Log.i("DATA",data);
                        //Log.i("DATAONE",strArrayOne+"");
                        Log.i("playlink",path);
                        playlink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View view) {
                                Intent intent1 = new Intent();
                                intent1.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                intent1.setData(Uri.parse(path));
                                startActivity(intent1);
                            }
                        });

                    }

                    appdetailadapter=new AndroidAppDetailAdapter(AndroidAppDetailActivity.this,strArrayOne);
                    viewpager.setAdapter(appdetailadapter);
                    tablayout.setupWithViewPager(viewpager);
                    //txtappdata.setText(jsonArray.get(po));



                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                error.printStackTrace();
            }
        }){
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params= new HashMap<String, String>();
                String appid=SharedPreference.get(Keys.SharedPref.SHR_APPID);
                Log.i("App_id",appid);
                params.put(Keys.APPDATA.APP_ID,SharedPreference.get(Keys.SharedPref.SHR_APPID));
                return params;
            }
        };

        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(getApplicationContext());
        queue.add(request);
     //   AppController.getInstance().add(request);

    }
}
```

And This is My View pager Adapter Code

```
public class AndroidAppDetailAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
public ArrayList<AndroidApp> banner_view;
public List<String> banimg;
String[] strArrayOne;
Context context;
LayoutInflater layoutInflater;



 public AndroidAppDetailAdapter(Context context,String[] strArrayOne)
    {
        this.context=context;
        this.strArrayOne=strArrayOne;
        layoutInflater=(LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Activity.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        //this.banner_view=banner_view;
        //banimg = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(banner_view.get(0).getBanner_img().split(",")));
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return strArrayOne.length;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object object) {
        return (view==(RelativeLayout)object);
    }

    @Override
    public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {

        View item_view1=layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.appdetailbanner,container,false);
        ImageView image_View= (ImageView) item_view1.findViewById(R.id.imgbanner);



        Log.i("FGG", Keys.BANNER_PATH + strArrayOne[position]);

     //   image_View.setImageResource(Keys.BANNER_PATH + ""strArrayOne[position]);
        Picasso.with(context)
               // .load("http://192.168.0.102/mindscriptApp/1.0/banner/srv.png")
                .load(Keys.BANNER_PATH + strArrayOne[position])
                .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .into(image_View);

        container.addView(item_view1);
        return item_view1;

    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        container.removeView((RelativeLayout)object);
    }
}
```

My log cat output is....

> ```
> 09-21 13:07:28.908 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/APPID: 1
> 09-21 13:07:28.951 31497-2619/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/App_id: 1
> 09-21 13:07:29.055 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/bannerimgees: [{"app_data":"Presenting to you Maratha Kranti Morcha related all the details , happenings, videos and all important information. Also upcoming Kranti Morcha for maratha reservations\/ Aarakshan with a calender is also available on the application.Details about events happening anywhere in maharashtra like pune,satara,kolhapur, sangli and amhednagar. You can now share all the information through WhatsApp and other social media applications. We also provide an option where in you can send any details that you have just by pressing the suchana button or send it through email.","banner_image":"srv.png,src.png,src3.png","play_link":"https:\/\/play.google.com\/store\/apps\/details?id=com.mindscript.marathakrantimorcha&hl=en"}] 
> 09-21 13:07:29.055 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/length: 1
> 09-21 13:07:29.057 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/DATA: srv.png,src.png,src3.png
> 09-21 13:07:29.057 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/playlink: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.mindscript.marathakrantimorcha&hl=en
> 09-21 13:07:29.064 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/FGG:  http://192.168.0.102/mindscriptApp/1.0/banner/srv.png
> 09-21 13:07:29.068 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/FGG:  http://192.168.0.102/mindscriptApp/1.0/banner/src.png
> 09-21 13:07:29.112 31497-31553/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0xb827e688 (GridView) with handle 0xb80d3a48
> 09-21 13:07:29.470 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication W/PathParser: Points are too far apart 4.000000596046461
> 09-21 13:07:45.777 31497-31497/mindscript.com.mindscriptapplication I/FGG:  http://192.168.0.102/mindscriptApp/1.0/banner/src3.png
> ```

Comment: maybe your device can't access your local server? how you access it?

Comment: Your device must be connected on Wifi or same network using on your laptop/desktop.

Comment: my device and laptop connected with same network, when  Picasso is load it shows error image

Answer (score 0):

Load image view with a sample url like this

```
Picasso.with(context)
              .load("http://www.jesslaversdesign.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/05/test-image-750x500px.jpg")
                //.load(Keys.BANNER_PATH + strArrayOne[position])
                .error(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera)
                .into(image_View);
```

if this is working check the URL from the server.

Comment: when loading single image its working fine but when passing multiple images its show error image